# Comparing two dataframes and store values based on conditions in python or R

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes, each with 2 columns (shown in the picture). I'm trying to define a function or perform an operation to scan `df2` on `df1` and store 
`df2["values"]` in `df1["values"]` if `df2["ID"]` matches `df1["ID"]`.

I want the result as shown in `New_df1` (picture)
I have tried a for loop with function `append()` but it's really tricky to make it work...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via `pandas.concat`, sorting and dropping druplicates:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[i, np.nan] for i in list('abcdefghik')],
                   columns=['ID', 'Values'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 2], ['c', 5], ['e', 4], ['g', 7], ['h', 1]],
                   columns=['ID', 'Values'])

res = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)\
        .sort_values(['ID', 'Values'])\
        .drop_duplicates('ID')

print(res)

#   ID  Values
# 0  a     2.0
# 1  b     NaN
# 1  c     5.0
# 3  d     NaN
# 2  e     4.0
# 5  f     NaN
# 3  g     7.0
# 4  h     1.0
# 8  i     NaN
# 9  k     NaN
```

Comment: you're a life saver :)